# How to remove whitespace around equation when \abovedisplayskip, \adobedisplayshortskip, ... don't work

Tags: spacing, equations, vertical-spacing

I've been dealing with this problem quite some time. I have this code

```
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=4cm,inner=2.5cm,outer=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
% Links utilizables en el PDF final %
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black,linktoc=all,hidelinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}
% Cuadros en definiciones %
\usepackage{mdframed}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
```

And this bit here

```
Formalmente, el producto cartesiano de $A$ y $B$ es el conjunto $A\times B$ cuyos elementos son pares ordenados $(x,y)$ tales que $x\in A$ y $y\in B$:

\begin{equation*}
A\times B = \{ (x,y) : x\in A, y\in B \}
\end{equation*}

texttexttext
```

The problem is, it's producing a big whitespace around the equation and after like an hour fixing a similar problem with a theorem environment, I got this new one. They don't seem to be related as if I change the theorem, equation keeps having that space around. I also found in this site that abovedisplayskip, belowdisplayskip and so on would do the thing but actually nothing happens.

[image: Screenshot of the page where equation is]

How to remove the space above and below the equation? Or if it's possible how to set a customizable option to change it?

Comment: never leave a blank line before a display math environment, and add `\raggedbottom` if you want any extra space at the bottom of the page.

Comment: you have _very_ large values for abovedisplayskip and belowdisplayskip it is hard to give specific advice as you have only provided fragments not a test file that produces the spacing shown.

Comment: Thanks! although removing the blank line doesn't fix the problem. @DavidCarlisle yeah forgot to set them back to 0 when posting. But no matter what value it has, it keeps showing the whitespace.

Comment: as I say you haven't provided a usable example. But why have you set the space above and below the equation so large the default natural sizes are 12pt and 7pt and you have set them as 100pt!!! and 10pt?, and presumably although you do not show it using `\flushbottom` so the page is stretched out.

Comment: presumably you have `\flushbottom` and the next thing in the file (at the top of the next page) is a large unbreakable box like a non-floating table that does not fit on this page.

Comment: after trying the `\flushbottom` and `\raggedbottom`, the last one seems to work fine. I guess it's what you said @DavidCarlisle. I'm just learning so never thought about that detail. Thanks a lot to both of you!